# How to refactor this controller action which builds an active record search hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring

This code doesnt feel right. I'm trying to make my controllers skinny and I feel like there is way too much logic in the controller action.

What would be a much better way of organising this code?

```
def search
    where_obj = {:status => 1}

    if params[:city].present?
        where_obj.merge! :city => params[:city]
    end

    if params[:county].present?
        where_obj.merge! :county => params[:county]
    end

    ## THERE WILL BE MANY MORE IF STATEMENTS HERE DUE TO GROWING SEARCH FORM

    @person = Person.where(where_obj)
end
```

As the search form grows this controller action will grow also. How can I keep my controller skinny?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
def search
  query = { :status => 1 }.merge(params.select { |k,_| [:city, :country].include?(k) })
  @person = Person.where(query)
end
```

Or a somewhat simpler version using the [`slice`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice) method provided by `ActiveSupport` (in Rails):

```
def search
  query = { :status => 1 }.merge(params.slice(:city, :country))
  @person = Person.where(query)
end
```

If you're going to have a bunch of different params to selectively include, then you could group them like this:

```
def search
  search_params = [:city, :country, :continent, ...]
  query = { :status => 1 }.merge(params.slice(*search_params))
  @person = Person.where(query)
end
```

(Thanks @ajcodez for pointing out the need for a splat on `search_params` when passed to `slice`.)

Comment: This will include the values irrespective of whether they are present or not, which is not what the OP's code was doing.

Comment: True, I guess we interpreted the question differently.

Comment: Your first proposal is good. As Sawa said, slice will have a different behavior that the OP `if` statements.

Comment: Both behave the same way as-is. To filter for non-empty values, the first solution would be simpler: `query = { :status => 1 }.merge(params.select { |k,v| v.present? && [:city, :country].include?(k) })`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def search
  @person = Person.where({status: 1}.merge(params).select{|_, v| v.present?})
end
```

Comment: That will include anything that is present in the `params` hash, which is not what the OP's code was doing.

Comment: I interpreted that `THERE WILL BE MANY MORE IF STATEMENTS HERE DUE TO GROWING SEARCH FORM` means that.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. You can define your fields as a constant too.

```
FIELDS = [:city, :country]

def search
  query_params = params.slice(*FIELDS).reject { |_,val| val.blank? }
  query_params[:status] = 1
  @person = Person.where query_params
end
```

Note the splat on the fields. Hash#slice: http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Slice.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, updated my answer with the splat.

Answer (score 1):

```
# controller
def search
  @person = PersonSearch.new(params).result
end


# lib/person_search.rb
class PersonSearch

  attr_accessor :params

  SUPPORTED_FIELDS = [:city, :country]

  def initialize(params)
    @params = params
  end

  def result
    Person.where conditions
  end

  private

  def conditions
    conditions = default_conditions

    SUPPORTED_FIELDS.each do |field|
      conditions.merge!(field => params[field]) if params[field]
    end

    conditions
  end

  def default_conditions
    { :status => 1 }
  end

end
```

Growing search form? Add more attributes to `SUPPORTED_FIELDS`.

*Pros:*

*+* Extendable (even support for other models)

*+* Testable (even without hitting your DB mostly)

*+* Reusable

*Cons:*

*-* slightly more code